# How can I increase the Hyper-V display resolution?

Tags: ubuntu, windows-8, virtual-machine, resolution, hyper-v

I just started experimenting with the Hyper-V of Windows 8 and installed Ubuntu on it. However when I launch it my screen resolution is small.

How can I scale Ubuntu to the resolution of my screen?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Install the Hyper-V Integration Services](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=41554). This provides better display/input/network integration between the guest and host.

Comment: This want help change the screen resolution of Hyper-V.

Comment: The link doesn't work any more, I got: We're sorry, this download is no longer available.

Comment: this answer is very outdated. Devid's answer below should be the accepted one.

Answer (score 36):

Here is how you can change the resolution of **Ubuntu (Linux)** running in Hyper-V:

- Install linux-image-extras (hyperv-drivers): `sudo apt-get install linux-image-extra-virtual`
- Open the Terminal and type: `sudo gedit /etc/default/grub`
- Find the line starting with `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT`, and add
  `video=hyperv_fb:1920x1080` (or your preferred resolution) in between
  the quotes (The maximum possible resolution is **1920x1080**) like this: `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash video=hyperv_fb:1920x1080"`
- Save and Exit
- Run `sudo update-grub`
- Restart Hyper-V (restarting Ubuntu (Linux) might be enough)

Increased display size of Hyper-V to 1680x1050. My Windows 8 display resolution is 1920x1200:

[image]

Comment: Worked for me on my Win 8.1 host and Ubuntu 14.04 guest.

Comment: Did not work for me using Windows 8.1 host and Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Comment: When using 1920x1080 resolution it work but didn't work with 1920x1200.

Comment: @Michael I described above that it won't work if the resolution is bigger than: 1920x1080

Comment: @Devid: I was jut confirming it still doesn't work at 1920x1200.  My fault for the misunderstanding.

Comment: Did not work initially - unable to locate package. Performed a 'sudo apt-get update' which fixed that. [2c]

Comment: Know i shouldn't use this for "thank yous", but this is the best description on the internet!

Comment: Worked well on Thinkpad X1 with Windows 10, and Ubuntu LTS 14.04 inside Hyper-V. Resolution is 1920x1080

Comment: Worked well on Windows 10 and Ubuntu 15.10 inside Hyper-V with resolution is 1920x1080.

Comment: This did not work for me. I'm on a custom Xidax PC with a resolution of 3840x2160. I've been running my PC at a much lower resolution for other reasons, but now that I've changed it back to 4k, it's tedious working on a miniature VM trying to troubleshoot the screen resolution.

Comment: On my Windows 10 pro, for internal provided Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS ubuntu, after running "sudo apt -y update" and "sudo apt -y upgrade", I only need to run "sudo apt-get install linux-image-extra-virtual", not need to manually make changes to Grub.

Comment: Is there nothing beyond 1080p possible with this? I can't seem to match the 2560x1440 resolution that the rest of my machine has.

Comment: +1 worked on Windows 8.1 running Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, however I had to use `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="video=hyperv_fb:1024x768"` (i.e. without the `quiet splash`  parts) and also restart my entire Windows machine (not just the VM) to get it to work. Don't forget to run `sudo update-grub` before the restart (e.g. if you change resolution), I found myself making this mistake many times!

Answer (score 5):

In the latest release of Ubuntu, the Hyper-V Integration Services are built into the kernel and won't help. Unfortunately even with windows, hyper-v won't display a larger resolution when accessing it through the virtual machine manager.

Try accessing it through VNC, you will be able to get a better resolution that way.

Comment: There is a way to change the screen resolution, just check my answer. VNC and RDP will display in Full Screen but the performance is not good.

Comment: Can you specify How to access it?

Answer (score 3):

I know this thread is old, but if it answers the question for others.

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

find:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="There is probably stuff here"
```

At the end add `splash video=hyperv_fb:1920x1080`

It should appear like

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet elevator=noop splash video=hyperv_fb:1920x1080"
```

then run

```
sudo update-grub
```

Enable BackPorts, for Jessie.

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/scources.list
```

add

```
deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian jessie-backports main

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get -t jessie-backports install hyperv-daemons
```

Reboot. Hopefully you will have joy!

Scobber

Comment: You pretty much replicated [Devid's answer](https://superuser.com/a/782046/243625), or do you think you added some value here?

Comment: All the solutions i had were exact to @devid. the one thing that got me over the line on a hyperv 2012 (not R2) host was the backports repository. adding that kernel param did nothing otherwise.

Comment: Ok, fair enough. Please edit your answer to highlight that difference and I will upvote it. (so formatting on it wouldn't hurt, either)

Comment: Super solution!

Comment: Why is 1080p the max?

Answer (score 2):

The following command will change the display resolution:

```
sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

Change the following line

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

to

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash video=hyperv_fb:1920x1080"
```

finally run this command:

```
sudo /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub
```

The above command is used, because `sudo update-grup` is not available anymore.

**Power off the virtual machine and start it again.**

The highest resolution is 1920 x 1080.

See as well

- https://askubuntu.com/questions/702628/ubuntu-hyper-v-guest-display-resolution-win-10-15-04
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/418666/update-grub-command-not-found

Comment: Why is 1080p the max?

Answer (score 1):

If your installation is using the Hyper-V DRM driver instead of hyperv_fb, the correct config should be `video=Virtual-1:...` instead of `video=hyperv_fb:...`.

In doubt, you could leave both in your grub CMDLINE config:
`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="video=Virtual-1:1920x1080 video=hyperv_fb:1920x1080"`

Comment: Finally Hyper-V DRM driver is working for my resolution 2240x1400. Thanks.
Can you provide the documentation for the configuration `video=Virtual-1:...` ?

Comment: I didn't find one at the time. I had to dig a lot to discover this.

Comment: I've found out that 'Virtual-1' is the default display device name on xfce display setting. So maybe it's just a default name.