# Hyper-V featuers missing, moving from virtual pc

Tags: windows-8, hyper-v, microsoft-virtual-pc, vhd

I use an instance of xp in virtual pc for some development tasks (old vb6 stuff etc). 
Now I'm in win 8 and setup hyper-v for this, and booted up my old vhd's in it.

I've noticed right off that hyper-v seems to be lacking some of the nicer features that virtual pc has- such as dynamic resizing of the hosted os screen resolution to make it match the windows size. It also doesn't seem to support the dynamic mouse tracking - ie, it must "capture" the mouse before you can use it.

I'm curious about a. what else may be lacking when compared to vpc and b. are these features scheduled to be added to it? Is it still possible to run VPC on windows 8?

update- Hadn't finished installed integration services, so now the mouse integration works. Screen resolution changing still not working though, and in addition I can't pick a wide screen resolution to use (the supports res'es are all 4x3)

Comment: you can install VPC 2007 with a hack, but this is not supported and my cause issues: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N5GV_-ehWrs

Comment: Did you install the [Integration Services](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732470(v=ws.10).aspx#BKMK_step4)?

Comment: Thought I had but seems it still needed a reboot. I see the mouse integration works now. I'll update the question. Other items still stand though?

Comment: @boomhauer: Yeah, I was hoping it would help with the mouse integration. Resizing the window to adjust desktop resolution is either not supported or has also never been working for me :(

Comment: check here: http://superuser.com/questions/518484/how-can-i-change-hyper-v-screen-resolution

Comment: didn't help, Devid