# Change screen resolution of Ubuntu VM in Hyper-V

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machine, resolution, hyper-v

Last night I was attempting to set up a Ubuntu VM on my device using Hyper-V. I had no problems with creating the VM, nor getting OS installed inside it and booted (apart from I incorrectly chose Generation 2 the first time), however, I've been having problem with changing the resolution of the Virtual Host when connected to it.

I've done a decent amount of searching, and problem solving, but so far, none of my attempts have worked. Here's is what I've tried, and citations where I got the solution (where I could find them again this morning):

1. Install Kubuntu 21.04 from their ISO and attempt to change the resolution in the display settings. No other options other than 1024x768 were present.
2. Per [this article](https://arcanecode.com/2020/12/28/adjust-the-screen-resolution-of-an-ubuntu-hyper-v-virtual-machine/) amend the contents of the grub file:

   1. Open a Terminal.
   2. Enter `sudo nano /etc/default/grub`
   3. Alter the line starting with `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` to add the resolution setting. In my case, this was `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash video=hyperv_fb:1920x1200"`
   4. Alter the line starting with `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUXT` to add the resolution setting. In my case, this was `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="quiet splash video=hyperv_fb:1920x1200"`
   5. Run `sudo update-grub`.
   6. Shut down the VM.
   7. Start the VM again.
   8. This resulted in a black screen, the VM was unusable.
3. Install `xrdp` per the [answer here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1251992/597903) on Ask Ubuntu and enable `EnhancedSessionTransportType`
4. Install Ubuntu 20.04 via the Hyper-V Quick Create menus. No luck.
5. Install `xrpd` on the Ubuntu 20.04 VM; no luck.
6. Amend grub (as above). No luck

This [answer](https://superuser.com/a/782046/888221) also suggests that the max resolution is 1920x1080 (really not what I want, I have a 1920x1200 display, I'd like to use all the pixels), so i also tried using that in grub's setting, along with installing `linux-image-extra-virtual`. Still Kubuntu 21.04 I get 1024x768.

What can I do here? I know it seems daft, but this should just *work*. I have no problems with creating VMs in Gnome Boxes, both Linux and Windows, and being able to change the resolution. Why isn't this **simple** functionality in Hyper-V? It's *literally* impossible to use the VM in 1024x768 on a screen that is 1920x1200; the applicable menu alone in the VM takes up the **entire** screen, and using an IDE is, well, far from an enjoyable experience.

Comment: I also tried setting Enhanced Session Mode in Hyper-V Manager but that did not help. I continue to work on this. (now Insider Windows 11 Pro and same issue).

Comment: Considering that some of the articles and Q&As I found date back to 2015, one would have *hoped* that this was an issue that Microsoft was both *aware* of and had fixed by now, @John . :(

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Below worked for me. Tested on Ubuntu 20.04 | Host Windows 11.

Open grub file.

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

Change value of GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT with below. Replace 3840x2160 with your highest resolution.

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash video=hyperv_fb:3840x2160"
```

Run below commands

```
sudo update-grub

sudo apt install linux-image-extra-virtual
```

Shutdown the VM and open PowerShell as administrator on host machine and run below. Replace "ubuntu" with your vm name. Change "3840" and "2160" with your highest resolution.

```
set-vmvideo -vmname ubuntu -horizontalresolution:3840  -verticalresolution:2160 -resolutiontype single
```

*This command may not be required. It is something I read on Kali blog.*

```
set-vm "Ubuntu" -EnhancedSessionTransportType HVSocket
```

Start VM. Open Ubuntu Display settings and choose scale 200.

Comment: This looks to have worked; though you missed a step of needing to shut down the VM between updating the settings in grub and using Powershell to alter the settings of the VM. It's been a some time since I moved from trying to configure the VM, so I'm going to rebuild it and test again before I accept.

Answer (score 40):

I'm running Ubuntu 22.04 and only needed the following PowerShell command:

```
set-vmvideo Ubuntu -horizontalresolution:1920 -verticalresolution:1080 -resolutiontype single
```

(Replace Ubuntu with your VM name and the resolution with your monitor's resolution)

Comment: This is what did it for me - spent a couple of hours searching for an answer tried everything else. Then just this powershell one liner - great +1. Now if I could only fix the mouse lag :/

Comment: Thanks! very elegant

Comment: First to remove mouse lags do : 
sudo nano /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
blacklist hyperv_fb
save (ctrl + x then y)
reboot
After that do above step to fix resolution issue

Comment: just make sure to run powershell in admin mode - worked for me on win 11 and hyper v ubuntu 22

Answer (score 2):

On Ubuntu 22.04 this seems to be sufficient to set the resolution

```
set-vmvideo Ubuntu -horizontalresolution:3840 -verticalresolution:2400 -resolutiontype single
```

BUT in my case the scale wasn't being saved after rebooting the VM so I had to set the following in the Ubuntu terminal [xrandr didn't work out for me]:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface scaling-factor 2
```

(for scaling 200%)

Answer (score 0):

If you've created your Ubuntu 22.04 VM by using the "Quick Create" function of Hyper-V Manager (which gives you a Microsoft-enhanced installation of Ubuntu) instead of installing your own ISO, the only solution that worked for me is:

1. Make sure that the Ubuntu VM has been started but you must not have an RDP connection to the VM.
2. Click on `Edit Session Settings…` for the VM in Hyper-V Manager.

   - If you've just started the VM, this menu option will not be there yet. You need to wait a minute.
3. This will start your RDP session with the right resolution (and should remember it for next time).

Notice that the list of resolutions is quite limited.

Answer (score -1):

Using generation2 VM in HyperV using Windows 11 Pro this also worked. Below I attached to help. When inside the grub file (After typing in sudo nano `etc/default/grub`), be sure to use <kbd>CRTL</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> to view the HELP menu which displays all of the hot keys & commands offered.

Here are the precise steps I took:

- I changed the two lines suggested with my resolution of 1920x1080
- Then pressed <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to initialize exit of the grub file
- Pressed Y and then ENTER to accept changes to file
- Then typed in sudo update-grub and hit ENTER again.
- I then typed in sudo reboot and reopened the session of Obuntu.

Tadaa, screen size fixed.

[Syntax of my grub file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WXaEk.png)

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)